# VirtualBox not displaying Ubuntu 17.04 correctly

Tags: graphics, virtualbox

I am trying to run Ubuntu 17.04 on Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.26 from an image that I downloaded from the Ubuntu website.

I have seemingly successfully installed Ubuntu correctly, however Ubuntu runs, I see the operating system load normally up until Ubuntu is supposedly fully loaded and what is displayed is a screen of graphics that is terribly distorted.

Here's a screenshot of what is displayed inside the operating system:

[image]

Within this screen, I can see the screen respond to my mouse movements, as if it does accept the input, but it's nothing that I can actually use.

Here is a screenshot of some of the settings I used for the Virtual Machine:

[image]

I'm wondering if anybody has had this problem before and knows how to fix this issue.

---

**Update**

It should be noted that at the time that this question was asked, the operating system was *not* installed.

After using the suggested actions within the accepted answer, I was able to install Ubuntu normally. Afterwards, I need to perform this sequence of button combinations a few times while loading Ubuntu in order to run the operating system.

Comment: @Henry WH Hack v2.1 - Thanks for that edit. For some reason I was not allowed to display the images that way.

Comment: This says turning off nested paging fixes this permanently. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1379062/comments/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As memory serves me, switching TTY's should fix the problem.

To fix your video problem, hit the  <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, followed by <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. It's a bug.

On some keyboards, you may have to <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

**Update #1:**

**Note:** You may have to issue the complete quoted key sequences a second time to get the screen to correct itself.

Comment: When I try this method, the screen goes black and displays the blinking underline cursor symbol and accepts no input. When I restart the VM afterwards, the original distortion screen shows up again.

Comment: What is your host key? Do your functions keys require holding down a `fn` key at the same time? Do the sequence twice and see if that works. Once running properly, make sure to install Guest Additions.

Comment: My host key is currently bound to *Right-Ctrl*. It seems that hitting *host_key* + *F1* after that sequence that you suggested fixed the problem.

Comment: It might be worth changing your answer to add the *host_key* + *F1* button combination to the end of the sequence that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@Sal, same thing happened to me.

All I did to fix it is press <kbd>host_key</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> once again.